# dc.js linechart not showing anything

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.lineChart to generate a line chart to show frequenct VS time. The following is my code

```
var freqchart=dc.lineChart("#chart1");
var ndx=crossfilter(data);
var countByTime=ndx.dimension(function (d) {

                return d.time;

        });

        var dateformat=d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y");
        var freqbyTimeGroup = countByTime.group()
                .reduceCount(function(d) { return d.time; });
    freqchart.width(400).height(200).transitionDuration(500)
        .dimension(countByTime).group(freqbyTimeGroup)
        .elasticY(true).x(
                d3.time.scale().domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.time}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.time})])).on("filtered", onFilt).yAxisLabel("Frequency").xAxisLabel('Time');
```

But I am getting the following blank thing without any graph.
[image]
Why can't I view the graph. What sort of change needed in my graph. I wan to show total events in a particular time period. There are many detectors giving response at the same time. I want to show the count of these detectors at a particular time.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? It's hard to troubleshoot without a simple self contained example

Comment: The first thing to check is that your group is returning the data your expect and not NaNs etc

Comment: Probably my group is returning NaNs. But why does it happen? I am confused what change is needed.

Comment: Can you see this link and help me to proceed. http://jsfiddle.net/y18LkwLt/

Comment: I have not added external resource for dc.js and d3.js in the jsfiddle

Comment: There were a number of things not working in the example code you sent. In the future, it would help to create a complete fiddle with the dependencies so that you can check that the basics like syntax and references to functions work. Still, I think I got it working and I'll summarize what I did in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a number of changes to your fiddle and got it to work.

Here is my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/6e67uzfn/11/

Some of the changes I made:

1. fixed the dates, which had invalid syntax. (Made up my own because I
   wasn't sure what you meant there.)
2. make a pass over the data to parse the dates using `dateformat.parse()`
3. call `chart.render()`
4. removed the argument to `group.reduceCount()`, which does not take any arguments
5. (probably the clue you were looking for) call `.xUnits(d3.time.days)` - this call is required so that dc.js knows what ticks to create on the x axis.

You will want to match the granularity of your `xUnits` with the granularity you use for date bins. You specify the bin granularity when you define the dimension or group, e.g. if you want to bin by days,

```
    var countByTime = data.dimension(function(d) { return d3.time.day(d.time); });
```

Otherwise it will use the exact time values, which are down to the millisecond and might not bin up at all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, I was not working with date. Rather time in H:M:S format.

Comment: Sure, you could definitely change the date format to parse times instead. (Your example had unquoted times and a date format so I wasn't sure quite what to do.) You may accordingly want to use `d3.time.hours` or `d3.time.minutes`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea

Comment: Hello. But its not working for time. Can you edit your fiddle for the time format. The fiddle is here. in the x axis its showing all the values instead of just minutes http://jsfiddle.net/6e67uzfn/13/

Comment: You mean the tick format? Does this help? `var minutesOnly = d3.time.format(':%M'); var xAxis = freqchart.xAxis().tickFormat(minutesOnly);` fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/6e67uzfn/15/

Comment: Hello Gordon Can you please See my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828802/time-is-repeating-in-dc-js-linechart-x-axis